# How to stop QGIS from looking for the wrong PostgreSQL host address in an existing workproject?

Tags: qgis, postgresql

It looks like a saved QGIS project workfile may be storing the old PostgreSQL host IP access details. Updates made to the PostgreSQL host IP in the main QGIS window are not being used in the project workfile.  The result is that when opening my project PostgreSQL looks for the wrong host and then comes up with a "time-out" and is stuck in a loop...

I attempted to set up a new PostgreSQL file with a revised host address etc and tested this successfully before accessing my project workfile.  However, I still get a time out error with PostgreSQL, as within the project workfile the pointer is still set at the old host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the project file in QGS or QGZ format?  If it is QGS, open the file in a text editor and do a find and replace on the old and new hostnames or ip addresses.  If the project is in QGZ format, open the QGZ file with 7-Zip or the file compression program of your choice.  Extract the QGS file in the QGZ file, update the hostname or address and put the updated QGS file back in the QGZ archive.

Comment: That worked! (it was a QGS file).  19 minutes to get a fix that must be a record?!

Comment: Most welcome to GIS.SE! I daresay, I had faster ones... ;-)

Comment: If the project was saved in the posgresql database then how did you edit the QGS or QGZ file? Where did you find it in your PC?